# How to preprocess group title render in views?

Tags: views, 8

I tried to preprocess a title of the group in the result of the rendering of the view.

Example:

Actual:

`Group 1 title
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
Group 2 title
Item 4
Item 5
Item 6`

Expected:

`<span class="test">Group 1 title<span>
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
<span class="test">Group 2 title</span>
Item 4
Item 5
Item 6`

Here the similar question on the drupal.org https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2950737.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the template for the title of the group, why don't you override the template file **views-view-grouping.tpl.php** for [Drupal 7](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme%21views-view-grouping.tpl.php/7.x-3.x), or **views-view-grouping.html.twig** for [Drupal 8](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21templates%21views-view-grouping.html.twig/8.2.x).

By standard Drupal templates names, overrides are also working with this one.

views-view-grouping--**MACHINEVIEWNAME**.tpl.php for a specific view

views-view-grouping--**MACHINEVIEWNAME**--**MACHINEDISPLAYNAME**.tpl.php for a specific display of a specific view.

Hope this can help you.